# How to determine unlock conditions

Tags: pokemon-battle-trozei

I've been enjoying the new Pokémon Trozei game ("Link Battle" outside the US - one of the few occasions where I feel the US name is better!) But one thing that's been frustrating me is the unlocks of certain Pokémon.

In many cases, it is enough to just flawlessly capture the Pokémon before it with a supereffective Scatter attack and that will usually meet some condition, but then there are others, like Dedenne:

> Have Pikachu as a partner Pokémon

I would never have guessed that! Is there any in-game way of finding out unlock requirement, or does it just rely on lucky guesses or looking it up online?

Comment: Probably luck and looking it up. Have you seen Inkay's evolution condition in the main series? You have to hold your 3DS upside down while it levels up. Litterally took me 3 tries even after I looked it up.

Comment: Hehe, yes, I know about Inkay :p PokéFarm Q has quite an interesting implementation of that ^_^